# Symfony form validation

Tags: symfony1

```
//creates a sfForm for the login
  $this->form = new sfForm();
  $this->form->setWidgets(array(
    'email' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default' => 'me@example.com')),
    'password' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword()
    )
  );

  //TODO: sfValidatorRegex on the password!
  $this->form->setValidators(array(
   'email' => new sfValidatorEmail(),
   'password' => new sfValidatorString(array(
    'min_length' => 8, 
    'max_length' => 255), 
    array(
     'min_length' => 'Password is too short. Minimum 8 characters required.')
   )));
```

Then after I check the request for a submit parameter

```
if($this->form->isValid(){
   loginUser();
}
```

It doesnt matter how short password, or fake email I put in, it fail ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not binding post data to the form.

You should put your form in a separate file, I'll assume you put it in `lib/form/LoginForm.class.php`.

In the form's `configure()` method create a name format: `$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat("login[%s]")`.

Your action's code:

```
$this->form = new LoginForm();
if ($request->isMethod("post")) {
  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter("login"));
  if ($this->form->isValid()) {
    //whatever
  }
}
```

Before creating an authentication and authorization system from scratch, have a look at the de-facto symfony standard of it: [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin). It has a propel version as well, called [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin).

Comment: I thought the authentication and auhtorization was already built into symfony. The authorization is set in security.yml and settings.yml? And the authentication is a $getUser->setAuthenticated. What I create is just the login and logout, to set and unset the 'authenticated'. Then I set up what to authoritize in the settings.yml and security.yml. Whats different with this plugin? I read the readme but there was no more documentation than installing. Thanks.

Comment: A basic system is built-in, like managing the current session's credentials or authentication. The plugin provides a standard way for user management - users, groups and credentials stored in the database.